# How many elements of a vector are smaller or equal to each element of this vector?

Tags: r, for-loop, vector

I am interested in writing a program that gives the number of elements of vector `x` that are smaller or equal to any given value within vector `x`.

Let's say

`x = [1,3,8,7,6,4,3,10,12]`

I want to calculate the number of elements within `x` which are smaller or equal to 1, to 3, to 8 etc. For example the fifth element of `x[5]` is `6` and the number of elements smaller or equal to `6` equals to `5`. However, I only know how to do an element-wise comparison, e.g `x[1]<=x[3]`

I suppose that I will be using the for loop and have something like this here:

```
for (i in length(x)){
       if (x[i]<=x[i]){
       print(x[i])}
       # count number of TRUEs
}
```

However, this code obviously does not do what I want.

Comment: sapply() works, thanks! Does `i` immediately mean the i-th element of `x`?

Comment: Yes exactly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `*apply` family as follows,

```
sapply(x, function(i) sum(x <= i))
#[1] 1 3 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `outer` to make all comparisons at once:

```
outer(x, x, "<=")
#       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8] [,9]
# [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# [7,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE TRUE
# [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE TRUE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE

colSums(outer(x, x, "<="))
#[1] 1 3 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
```

Comment: Perfect! The only thing you have to take into account is that you are considering each element in the sum, so depending on your interest, you have to subtract one unit to each value or not.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `findInterval`

```
findInterval(x, sort(x))
#[1] 1 3 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
```

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use `rank`, which ranks the values. Setting the ties.method argument to "max" retrieves the inclusive value ("<=" versus "<").

```
rank(x, ties.method="max")
[1] 1 3 7 6 5 4 3 8 9
```

Comment: This is the best solution.